# Sonarqube for both coverity and coverage

Tags: sonarqube

We are implementing sonarqube 6.7 for analyzing coverity and coverage. Using sonar-coverity plugin we were successful in pulling the results to sonar dashboard. But, the coverage analysis is not working ( its 0% ). The issue is sonar.language property.

```
sonar.language=cov-cpp ( for coverity analysis )
sonar.language=c++ ( for coverage )
```

How to get both the reports on the same dashboard ( on same set of .c,.cpp ) files ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `sonar.language` is *deprecated* is that it forces a mono-language analysis. Thus, only one or the other is going to work, depending on which "saved last".

Presumably, you have both of those languages declaring C++ and claiming its file extensions. This is a fundamental issue which means that the two plugins simply won't work together. Either you need the Coverity plugin to import your coverage reports *or* you need it to not declare C++ so that it can play nicely with a "base" language plugin that: declares the language, claims its file extensions, and delivers basic metrics and rules.

Comment: We removed sonar.language property from sonar.properties. Also, removed sonar-cxx plugin assuming coverity plugin will try to evaluate the coverage report. But, in this case, all the values are 0. Please let us know how to proceed ?

Comment: Sorry @UreRamya. I don't have experience with either of those plugins.